# SwiftUI: Keep VideoPlayer playing while device is locked

Tags: swiftui, avplayer

title says it all as far as I'm aware. I have the following view:

```
struct VideoView: View{
    @State var FilePath = ""
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    var body: some View{
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .onAppear{
                player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: FilePath)!)
                player.play()
            }.onDisappear{
                player.pause()
            }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this in my ContentView, and it works fine. But when I close the app, or when the device is locked, the video stops playback. Is there a way that I can change this so that it will keep playing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a while to figure it out, but I eventually came up with the following solution.

1. make sure that you enable `Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture` under `Signing and Capabilities`
2. When you define your `AVPlayer`, add the following code:

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: FilePath)!)
do{
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}catch{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
player.audiovisualBackgroundPlaybackPolicy = .continuesIfPossible
```

3. You're done, your video will now play when your device is locked or you are in another app. Note that playback controls do not show on the simulator, however it works fine on the device.